# What does cache means in Marklogic from administrative perspective?

Tags: marklogic

I would like to gather knowledge on what does cache means in Marklogic and what is it significance from an administrative point of view.

Answer (score 3):

There are several different caches that all work in slightly different ways, but they all fit the general definition of a cache that stores frequently accessed data on higher bandwidth storage (usually RAM, but sometimes SSD) so that it can be retrieved more quickly.

There are many articles about this topic in MarkLogic documentation, but here are a few:

https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/performance/perftune#id_56362
https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/concepts/clustering
https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/performance/query_meters